# How to Make Legend Display Correctly in Dual Axis Bar/Line Graph

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code that produces the graph below. Everything is correct except the display of the legend. I want the legend to show the color designations for each of the lines but it is only showing my first variable as it appears in the code I wrote which attempts to add the legend. Also the color for `%_ESI_3` should be green and not `slategray`.

Any thoughts on how to add `%_ESI_3`, `%_ESI_4`, and `%_ESI_5` to the legend with the correct color designations?

```
UMC_Cobmined_Plot.plot(ax=g8, x='Week', y='Total', kind='bar', subplots=True, color='slategray')
UMC_Cobmined_Plot[['%_ESI_3']].plot(ax=g8, secondary_y=True, marker ='d', mark_right=False, color=('green'))
UMC_Cobmined_Plot[['%_ESI_4']].plot(ax=g8, secondary_y=True, marker ='d', mark_right=False, color=('dodgerblue'))
UMC_Cobmined_Plot[['%_ESI_5']].plot(ax=g8, secondary_y=True, marker ='d', mark_right=False, color=('purple'))
g8.set_title('UMC LWBS Acuity % By Volume')
g8.set_ylabel('Total Patients')
g8.right_ax.set_ylabel('% LWBS By Acuity')
g8.tick_params(labelrotation=90)
g8.set_xlabel('')
g8.legend(['%_ESI_3','%_ESI_4','%_ESI_5'],
          loc='upper left', frameon=False)
```

[image]

Data Sample:

```
Week       Total    %_ESI_3 %_ESI_4  %_ESI_5
07/03/2021  470      2.0    4.0       1.0
07/10/2021  477      2.0    3.0       2.0
07/17/2021  517      2.0    6.0       3.0
```

Comment: Hi Raven, could you please provide a full [mcve]?

Comment: I'd be happy to edit my response to meet your standards, what exactly is it lacking/needing?

Comment: What happens if you add a `label` parameter to the `plot` method in the first lines and use just `g8.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False)` in the last line?

Comment: The legend only show the 'Total' variable as slategray. No other variables in the legend,

Comment: You can add a sample of the data for example. So we can easily reproduce.

Comment: Done - just edited my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing a lot of information. But the basic idea would be:

```py
UMC_Cobmined_Plot.plot(ax=g8, x='Week', y='Total', kind='bar', subplots=True, color='slategray')
g8bis = g8.twinx()
UMC_Cobmined_Plot[['%_ESI_3']].plot(ax=g8bis, x='Week', marker ='d', mark_right=False, color=('green'))
UMC_Cobmined_Plot[['%_ESI_4']].plot(ax=g8bis, x='Week', marker ='d', mark_right=False, color=('dodgerblue'))
UMC_Cobmined_Plot[['%_ESI_5']].plot(ax=g8bis, x='Week', marker ='d', mark_right=False, color=('purple'))
g8.set_title('UMC LWBS Acuity % By Volume')
g8.set_ylabel('Total Patients')
g8bis.set_ylabel('% LWBS By Acuity')
g8.tick_params(labelrotation=90)
g8.set_xlabel('')
g8bis.legend(['%_ESI_3','%_ESI_4','%_ESI_5'],
          loc='upper left', frameon=False)
```

Note that `g8` and `g8bis` are internally two different subplots that lie on the same spot, with `g8` having a y-axis at the left, and `g8bis` a y-axis at the right. If you do `g8 = g8.twinx()` you loose the variable that points to the first subplot.

Answer (score 0):

I had to completely change my code to this and it works as desired:

```
g8.bar(UMC_Cobmined_Plot['Week'],UMC_Cobmined_Plot['Total'], color='slategray', label = 'Total')
g8.set_ylabel('Total Volume')
g8=g8.twinx()
g8.plot(g8.get_xticks(), UMC_Cobmined_Plot['%_ESI_3'].values, linestyle='-', marker='o', linewidth=2.0, color=('green'))
g8.plot(g8.get_xticks(), UMC_Cobmined_Plot['%_ESI_4'].values, linestyle='-', marker='o', linewidth=2.0, color=('dodgerblue'))
g8.plot(g8.get_xticks(), UMC_Cobmined_Plot['%_ESI_5'].values, linestyle='-', marker='o', linewidth=2.0, color=('purple'))
g8.set_ylabel('% LWBS By Acuity')
g8.set_title('UMC LWBS Acuity % By Volume')
g8.legend(["%_ESI_3", "%_ESI_4","%_ESI_5"])
```